# Missing text when I print Pages 5.1 file or export to PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, pages

I've encountered a problem whereby if I want to print a pages 5.1 file or export it to PDF, text goes missing (specifically text near superscript/subscript text). An example of this same problem can be found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25041681#25041681) however the 'solution' there doesn't work.

I'd be very grateful for any advice or solutions.

Comment: So you are saying you have the problem even when tables are not being used?

Comment: No, the problem is exclusive to the text inside tables.

Comment: Just hit the same bug. Circumvented it by exporting to Pages09, opening in pages09, and exporting to PDF from there. This doesn't work very well, but for a one off was okay. **Shame on Apple** for not fixing this well known bug in Pages13.